# Maude-system can an operation have more than two operands?

Tags: maude-system

I know that in maude you can define an operation in one of the following ways:

```
op operation_: Nat -> Bool . // for 1 operands
op _operation_: Nat Nat -> Bool . // for 2 operands
```

But is there a way to define the operataion such that it will have more operands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the ternary conditional opertator (from the Basic Maude) should be a good example: "the presence of underscores in a function name imply that we are using mixfix. The idea is that each argument of the function will replace one of the underscores. For example, consider

```
op if_then_else_fi : Bool Nat Nat -> Nat .
```

We could then apply this operator like this:

```
if B then X else Y fi
```

where B is a Boolean, and X and Y are Nats."

No limits on operator arity is mentioned in [manual](http://maude.cs.illinois.edu/w/images/e/e0/Maude-2.7.1-manual.pdf) (read pp.33-35 to embrace the full power of operator declaration), so

```
op _ _operation_ _ _: Nat Nat Nat Nat Nat -> Bool . // for 5 operands
```

should be ok too. I guess at some point you should hit implementation specific, platform, or memory limit.

Comment: if you do that, you get the following error: "number of underscores (2) does not match number of arguments (5) for
    operator _operation_."

Comment: Apparently "if underscores present should match arity". Add few more underscores, or remove completely